# Is this a good workout split? It is modified for preference, but I would still like some review

Tags: muscle, hypertrophy

4 day split. Modified upper lower for preference.

Monday (upper):
Dumbbell bench 3x8-10
Lat pull-down 3x12-15
Facepull 3xamrap
Low cable bicep curl 3x12-15
Incline dumbbell bench 3x8-10
Bent over one arm row 3x10-12
Incline bicep curl 3x10-12

Tuesday (lower):
Bulgarian split squat 3x 8-15 depending on weight
Triceps extensions 3x12-18
Standing calf raise 5x20
Lateral raise 5x10-15
Hip thrusts 3x12-15
Cable Y raise 3x 10-12

Wednesday: Rest

Thursday(upper)
Friday(lower)

Answer (score 1):

Few suggestions:

- your leg routine is pretty thin. In my opinion any leg routine should include squats and deadlift or some variants of them.
- your shoulder exercises are a bit imbalanced. You have 2 exercises targeting the side delts and none for the front delts. I would suggest removing one of the side delt raises snd add in a overhead press for your front delts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. 

I currently have very over developed quads compared to my hams and glutes and calves which is why I only have the split squat which hits both quads and glutes. Sometimes I incorporate dumbbell Rdls for a couple months and then swap them out.